# VB.NET: Remove the .png from name

Tags: vb.net, string

"Image.png"

How do I remove the .png part? My program seems to be having trouble with it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Dim fileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("Image.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can know that the name will not have another dot(.) in it, this should work.

```
Dim filename As String = "image.png"
filename = filename.split(".")(0)
```

If on the otherhand, the filename is from some user input, this will not work. For example, there could be file names like

```
sunset.greek.png
```

In which case my code would return only the `sunset`.